# Recursively Convert all Arrays to Objects in Multidimensional Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Consider the following object:

```
const data = {
    foo: 'bar',
    items: [
        {
            id: 1,
            items: [
                {
                    id: 50,
                    content: 'test'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            items: [
                {
                    id: 70,
                    content: 'test'
                },
                {
                    id: 85,
                    content: 'test'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I am currently utilising the [Vuex-i18n](https://github.com/dkfbasel/vuex-i18n) plugin which only supports string values within arrays, thus I need to iterate through my data and convert all arrays into objects.

I was hoping that I would be able to utilize [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) in some way but I haven't been able to get it to work.

This is what I tried:

```
const json = '{"foo":"bar","items":[{"id":1,"items":[{"id":50,"content":"test"}]},{"id":2,"items":[{"id":70,"content":"test"},{"id":85,"content":"test"}]}]}';

console.log(JSON.parse(json, (key, value) =>
  typeof value === 'array'
    ? Object.assign({}, value)
    : value
));
```

Can anyone suggest a way in which this can be achieved? I was hoping that I could avoid recursively iterating over the object but I am not sure if that is possible...

## Update

The expected output should look like this:

```
const data = {
    foo: 'bar',
    items: {
        0: {
            id: 1,
            items: {
                0: {
                    id: 50,
                    content: 'test'
                }
            }
        },
        1: {
            id: 2,
            items: {
                0: {
                    id: 70,
                    content: 'test'
                },
                1: {
                    id: 85,
                    content: 'test'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note all the arrays are now objects...

Comment: Could you include an example of what the desired output is?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: "*convert all arrays into objects*" what should this produce? An array-like? Something else?

Comment: Absolutely, give me 2 secs

Comment: no. you can not have nested objects without keys.

Comment: @NinaScholz - I am aware of that, I was hoping that by converting it to an object, it would just use the array keys as the object keys. It seems your answer does exactly this!

Comment: `items: { { id: 50, content: 'test' } }` is invalid syntax. An object needs key-value pairs and you don't have that when you've replaced `[]` with `{}`

Comment: @VLAZ - Good point, I did it quickly because I wanted to update it for you but it should be pretty clear what I need. I believe Nina has nailed it

Comment: @BenCarey it's not clear at all. I was already guessing with the array-like (and guessed correctly) but there was about equal chance I guessed wrong. Your example then middled the waters further by being invalid. If it *was* pretty clear, you wouldn't have gotten *three questions* for what you actually wanted immediately after posting a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could check for array with [`Array.isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray).

```js
const json = '{"foo":"bar","items":[{"id":1,"items":[{"id":50,"content":"test"}]},{"id":2,"items":[{"id":70,"content":"test"},{"id":85,"content":"test"}]}]}';

console.log(JSON.parse(json, (key, value) => Array.isArray(value)
    ? Object.assign({}, value)
    : value
));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much!